# How to install and use docker in the same gitlab CI step?

Tags: linux, permissions, docker, gitlab

I use a gitlab-runner with a custom executor which creates and destroys virtual machines on KVM hypervisor. The installation and configuration are very similar to this example: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/custom_examples/libvirt.html

In a single CI step (and therefore on a clean CentOS 7), I want to:

- Install docker (daemon and CLI)
- Add the user `gitlab-runner` to the group `docker`
- Run some docker stuff with gitlab-runner user

A (non working) example of `.gitlab-ci.yml` is:

```
docker:
  before_script:
    - sudo yum install -y docker-ce containerd.io # And whatever else is required for this line to succeed.
    - sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
    - newgrp docker
  script:
    - docker run hello-world
  tags:
    - vm
```

The previous example fails with `permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock` because the commands following `newgrp` are executed in the original shell session and not the one created by `newgrp`.

Changing the ownership of `/var/run/docker.sock` to `root:gitlab-runner` could be a (not tested) solution but feels very wrong.

Interestingly, whatever is in the `after_script` section is executed in a new SSH session and therefore with updated group information. Unfortunately, `before_script` and `script` seem to be concatenated and given in one block to the `run_exec` script.

Is there a way to either "refresh" the groups of the `gitlab-runner` user within the same CI step, or allow this same user to use docker without adding it to the `docker` group?

Comment: Quick update that changing the ownership of `/var/run/docker.sock` to `root:gitlab-runner` works. It still feels very wrong, tough.